# Drupal 7 renders the whole website as text

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I recently deployed to fortrabbit and it's broken beyond life. I removed symlink from main htacess file and one in default/files. No errors in logs (there was permission error on file system, but I changed it and the error went away.

[image]

What?why?What?Ideas?

Comment: did you try to flush the cache?

Comment: of course. I think there are still problems with permissions in default/files, but I cannot run chmod because it says I don't have permissions and 'sudo' doesn't seem to be installed.

Comment: Can't you change the folder (755) or file (644) permissions by right clicking on items in your FTP client?

Comment: Yeah I just did that, now getting "The specified file temporary://fileWXOl7U could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log."

Comment: Did you check if the tmp directory can be found (admin -> file system)?

Comment: Your css files are correctly linked ? Are they aggregated ?

Comment: I had created the temp folder, but that didn't solve it. The solution what commenting out .htaccess contents in sites/default/files, because the hosting service I use "fortrabbit" apparently doesn't like it.

Comment: I have run into this too. The way our webserver is set up, we can't include any options in our .htaccess files. The hard part comes when modules (or Drupal itself, I'm not clear which) add in a basic .htaccess file if it doesn't already exist in certain directories. This basic .htaccess file includes options! But the owner of the file is the webserver, so I can't edit it myself! So I had to use a hack to make it writable, change it, then revert the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was commenting out .htaccess contents in sites/default/files, because the hosting service I use "fortrabbit" apparently doesn't like it